# FastAPI Sqlalchemy Error: sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: cvb@example.com

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

Getting error

```
in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "cvb@example.com"
LINE 3: WHERE "User".id = 'cvb@example.com'
```

while connecting to aws rds postgres however when connected to sqlite the data succesfully injected in database.

Could please me with the possible solution.

Please find the code below.

Model.py

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "User"


    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(255))
    first_name  = Column(String(255))
    last_name = Column(String(255))
    phone = Column(Integer)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, phone, password, *args, **kwargs):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.password = hashing.get_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return hashing.verify_password(self.password, password)
```

Services

```py
class UserServices(BaseService[User, UserCreate, UserUpdate]):
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        super(UserServices, self).__init__(User, db_session)

    def create(self, obj: UserCreate) -> User:
        user = self.db_session.query(User).get(obj.email)
        if user:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=400,
                detail=f"User with email = {obj.email} is already exist.",
            )
        return super(UserServices, self).create(obj)

    def get_user_email(self, obj: str) -> User:
        user = self.db_session.query(User).get(obj)
        if user is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=400,
                detail=f"User with email = {obj} not exist.",
            )
        return obj
```

Session.py

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:password2@hostname:5432/postgres"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)



@lru_cache
def create_session() -> scoped_session:
    Session = scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    )
    return Session


# Dependency
def get_session() -> Generator[scoped_session, None, None]:
    Session = create_session()
    try:
        yield Session
    finally:
        Session.remove()
```

db/users.py

```py
from typing import List, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr, constr, validator
from .utils import to_camel


from phonenumbers import (
    NumberParseException,
    PhoneNumberFormat,
    PhoneNumberType,
    format_number,
    is_valid_number,
    number_type,
    parse as parse_phone_number,
)
MOBILE_NUMBER_TYPES = PhoneNumberType.MOBILE, PhoneNumberType.FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE

class UserEmail(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr


class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: EmailStr
    phone: constr(max_length=50, strip_whitespace=True) = None
    user_type= str
    is_active: Optional[bool] = True
    is_superuser: bool = False

    @validator('phone')
    def check_phone_number(cls, v):
        if v is None:
            return v

        try:
            n = parse_phone_number(v, 'GB')
        except NumberParseException as e:
            raise ValueError('Please provide a valid mobile phone number') from e

        if not is_valid_number(n) or number_type(n) not in MOBILE_NUMBER_TYPES:
            raise ValueError('Please provide a valid mobile phone number')

        return format_number(n, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL if n.country_code == 44 else PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        orm_mode = True
        alias_generator = to_camel
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

class UserCreate(User):
    password: str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        alias_generator = to_camel
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

class UserUpdate(User):
    pass
```

I am new to the Fastapi and trying to connect aws rds postgres

Comment: It will be helpful if you indicate which line the error occurs on - generally, it seems like you're trying to query for a row with the `id` field by giving an email address.

Comment: It worked in `SQLite` because sqlite basically ignores types. Use `psql` to look at your `User` table in the database, I'm betting the ORM set an integer `id` field.

Comment: +1 to what @AdrianKlaver said: you tried to change the `id` column from `Integer` to `String`, but `autoincrement=True` likely means it's going to force it to be an `Integer` regardless: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement see: "Set up “auto increment” semantics for an integer primary key column with no foreign key dependencies" - SQLite types are advisory while PostgreSQL enforces them.